# Связь один ко многим Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, java

Добрый день! Я только начал знакомство с Hibernate и сразу столкнулся с проблемой.
В моей *MySQL* БД есть некоторая таблица **result**, которая кроме всего прочего имеет *foreign key* поле *test_id*.
Я получаю *entity*-объект таблицы *result* и хочу получить так же поле *test_id* из другой таблицы. Проблема в том, что после получения *entity*-объекта сессия закрывается и достать значение по внешнему ключу я не могу! Посдкажите решения!
PS Я использую пример из этой статьи:

[hibernate для начинающих](http://habrahabr.ru/post/29694/)

Comment: это устаревший пример. Посмотрите дату поста там аж 2008 год. с тех пор уже много воды утекло.

Comment: вообще капец, фреймворк так стремительно и радикально меняется!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Посмотрите вот эту статью с примером [Hibernate – One-To-Many Example (Annotation)](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/)

[Hibernate Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/hibernate-tutorials/)